# whats the best way to bottle home made condiments and spice rubs?

Tags: food-safety

A jar of harissa made by me just exploded at a friends house, why would this happen?

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is more likely due to the ingredients than how you bottled it.

Comment: How was it processed when you put it in the jar?  And how was it stored?  This can happen if you don't fully pasteurize items in glass jars, and then either store it for too long in the fridge, or at a warm temperature, as the microbial activity creates gas as a byproduct, which increases the pressure of the container.

Comment: This has been covered on the site many times, but here a duplicate which involves an "exploding" jar - in his case the cap wasn't firmly connected to the glass, so the condiment spouted out instead of exploding the glass, but it is the same principle.